Adding a line on the table of content manually using Hebrew numbering in Overleaf file (Latex code)
I have to add to my thesis a line in the table of the content manually of Hebrew abstract with number "א", please see attached figure to understand what I mean, here is my Latex code, I tried in many ways and couldn't do that, I will be happy for you help:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backref=none]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue,
}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{acronym}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    width=150mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
    bindingoffset=6mm,
    margin=1in
}



% Define the erfc function if not defined
\DeclareMathOperator{\erfc}{erfc}


\usepackage{array} % Additional package for extended column formatting
\usepackage{subcaption} % Add this package
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\usepackage[]{amsthm} %lets us use \begin{proof}
\usepackage[]{amssymb} %gives us the character \varnothing
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=10pt}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\gauss}{G}

\usepackage{pdfpages} % Add this line
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,maxbibnames=20]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\input{title}
\input{supervisor}

\chapter*{Acknowledgement}
\input{Acknowledgement}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter*{List of Acronyms}
\input{Acronyms}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\onehalfspacing
\clearpage % Ensure a page break before changing the numbering
\pagenumbering{roman} % Switch to Roman numbering

% Manually add the Abstract to the ToC
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\input{Abstract}

% Ensure a page break before switching to Arabic numbering
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Switch to Arabic numbering for the main content

\chapter{Introduction and Motivation}
\input{introduction}

...... other chapters included

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{א}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Hebrew Abstract}
\begin{hebrew}
\input{Hebrewpart}
\end{hebrew}


\end{document} 

In the line  \input{Hebrewpart} I include the Hebrew material as pdf file, I just need to add to a line in my table of contents of my thesis (Hebrew abstarct א as in the attached figure  

You need to use \includepdf{} to include a PDF rather than source, don't you?

The problem is not including the material, I include it, my problem is manually adding a line in the table of contents, the line is "Hebrew Abstrac..............א"

It was just a comment. You've not provided any code I could reproduce the problem with and it is not something I can divine simply by eye-balling your code. Somebody else may be able to, but I can't.  EDIT: Since you weren't flagged as new, I thought you'd have been advised about providing MWEs, but I just looked at your history and I don't think that happened. So sorry about that. Apparently the site thinks merely being registered in absentia imparts knowledge of its ways. Here's some help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

Off-topic: you are loading things in the wrong order and sometimes twice with different options. You probably are loading things you don't need, too. You should sort your preamble out to avoid (other) problems. On-topic: You don't seem to have set up any font which could typeset a Hebrew character? Or did I miss it? And in what way doesn't it work? Do you get an error? Nothing in the toc? The wrong thing? Which engine are you using?

I did something similar with a dumb hack, using the Latex character "\aleph" instead of the actual Hebrew letter. I just can't deal with Hebrew in Latex.
Basically take the last part of OP's code, and replace א with $\aleph$:
in the document itself, before inputting the Hebrew pdf, I put:
\renewcommand\thepage{$\aleph$}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 4mm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Hebrew abstract}

Then I included the Hebrew part with
\includepdf{hebrew_abstract.pdf}

The page numbering of the latex file doesn't seem to actually add the א to the bottom of the hebrew_abstract.pdf, so I just manually added the א to the bottom of hebrew_abstract.pdf . Resulting table of contents looks like this:

The hyperlink to the Hebrew abstract in the TOC doesn't seem to work properly though (it goes to page 71 instead of א).
P.S., if anyone arriving here also has to include a Hebrew table of contents like I had to, my hacky solution was to just manually type it in Word and merge the pdfs or \includepdf directly in the big Latex file.
